# rank function for mysqli 5.7 version

Tags: sql, mysql, rank, mysql-5.7

I was using the Rank() function on mysql and it was not working. I want exactly the rank function type of codes which skips one rank after double rank occurs and I didn't get any.

This is the query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT tblstudents.StudentId,tblstudents.StudentName,tblstudents.RollId,tblclasses.ClassName,tblclasses.Section,tblresult.ClassId,tblresult.amh,tblresult.eng,tblresult.math,tblresult.art,tblresult.hpe,tblresult.oro,tblresult.sc,tblresult.it,tblresult.ss,tblresult.cv,tblresult.mt,tblresult.amh+tblresult.eng+tblresult.math+tblresult.art+tblresult.hpe+tblresult.oro+tblresult.sc+tblresult.it+tblresult.ss+tblresult.cv+tblresult.mt as markk ,tblresult.amh/2+tblresult.eng/2+tblresult.math/2+tblresult.art/2+tblresult.hpe/2+tblresult.oro/2+tblresult.sc/2+tblresult.it/2+tblresult.ss/2+tblresult.cv/2+tblresult.mt/2  as per from tblresult join tblstudents on tblstudents.StudentId=tblresult.StudentId  join tblclasses on tblclasses.id=tblresult.ClassId WHERE tblresult.ClassId=:classid";
```

```
Name       Rank
X            1
Y            2
Z            2
A            4
```

Comment: MySQL 5.7 reaches end of life next month. It's time to upgrade.